# Заблокировать удаление первых 4 символов в editText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

То есть, дописывать можно, и стирать дописанный текст, а первые 4 символа должны оставаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195571/3212712) надо назначить слушатель событий ввода текста и в них проверять заданное условие:

   ```
   final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   edt.setText("http");
   Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());
   edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
   {
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
      {

      }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
           int after)
      {
           //Не тестировал, но, по идее, можно и тут следить за соблюдением условия
           if(count<4)
           {
               edt.setText("http");
               Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());
           }
      }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
       {
           if(!s.toString().startsWith("http"))
           {
               edt.setText("http://");
               Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Или можно перед `EditText` расположить `TextView`, содержащий нужные вам символы.